# How to convert a #define definition into a string in VS2008?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008

Say, if I have an exported function defined as such in `VS2008`:

```
#define myExportedFunction fn1

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL WINAPIV myExportedFunction(int val)
{
    return val == 2;
}
```

So how do I create a string out of `myExportedFunction` preprocessor definition to use as such?

```
BOOL(WINAPIV *pfn_myExportedFunction)(int val);

HMODULE hDll = ::LoadLibrary(strMyDllPath);
(FARPROC&)pfn_myExportedFunction = ::GetProcAddress(hDll, myExportedFunction);  //Causes: error C2065: 'fn1' : undeclared identifier
```

Comment: Why don't you use `#define myExportedFunction "fn1"`?

Comment: @Danh: So how would it work for the function export name then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use prepocessor operator:

```
#define myExportedFunction fn1
#define TO_STR_(X) #X
#define TO_STR(X) TO_STR_(X)

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL WINAPIV myExportedFunction(int val)
{
    return val == 2;
}

BOOL(WINAPIV *pfn_myExportedFunction)(int val);

HMODULE hDll = ::LoadLibrary(strMyDllPath);
(FARPROC&)pfn_myExportedFunction = ::GetProcAddress(hDll, TO_STR(myExportedFunction));
```

Comment: OK. Thanks. Can you explain though what you're doing with `#x` and `TO_STR_`?

Comment: @c00000fd, those are preprocessor operations. [read up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_stringification)